# Why AddressSanitizer report wild pointer as a heap-buffer-overflow instead of use-after-free

Tags: clang, address-sanitizer

```
class ISettingChangedListener
{
public:
    virtual void NotifySettingsChanged() = 0;
};

class View : public ISettingChangedListener {
    // ...
}

// Set the listener as a pointer to a view
void System::SetListener(ISettingChangedListener *listener) {
    m_settings_changed_listener = listener;
}

// view is destroyed somewhere by delete

// after a while when the settings is about to change

void System::ChangeSettings() {
    // do some modify
    m_settings_changed_listener->NotifySettingsChanged(); // report a heap-over-flow instead of use-after-free
}
```

The code flow is comment above. Is it because that the freed memory get reallocated by other code or something else ?

Another test code result in `use-after-free` when `NotifySettingsChanged` get called immediately after the `View object` is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `use-after-free` can only be detected for relatively recent deallocations (as long as they fit in quarantined memory). You can increase detectability by setting higher value in `ASAN_OPTIONS=quarantine_size_mb=512` (default is 256 on x86 and 16 on Android/iOS) but this can not fix the root cause.

In your particular case the memory was probly reallocated with smaller size so Asan thought you have heap overflow.

Comment: where should I put the option ?

Comment: @zoujyjs To `ASAN_OPTIONS` environment variable.